# Handling events in VB6: Initialize

Tags: events, vb6, event-handling, initialization

Here is my question. I have VB6 class `FirstClass`. In `SecondClass` i create instance of `FirstClass`:

```
WithEvents fClass as FirstClass

...

Set fClass = New FirstClass
```

Ok. Also in `SecondClass` I have an event `Initialize` - this is some event of `FirstClass`'s object (as far as i can understand). But when I paste breakpoint in this event, it doesn't fire. So could you please explain me why I can't go in this event and how the events handling works in VB6 in general.
Please, ask questions if my English isn't good for understanding my thoughts

Update:

Here is property from FirstClass:

Private Property Let IRPCAppMode_Application(RHS As Object)

```
Const METHOD_NAME As String = "IRPCAppMode_Application" 'DO NOT TRANSLATE
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set mApp = RHS
Set m_objRPCProject = mApp.Project
Set m_objDataSet = m_objRPCProject.CurrentDataSet

RaiseEvent Initialize
```

...

I know that mApp object sets only in this line of code, that's all. What i can't understand is how Initialize Event rises in SecondClass and how can we set private property outside of class. Calling of Initialize in SecondClass:

```
Private Sub m_objTestMode_Initialize()
    Const METHOD_NAME As String = "m_objTestMode_Initialize" 'DO NOT TRANSLATE
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim lLoop As Long
    Set mRPCProject = m_objTestMode.Project
    SetupAutoSaveTimer
    SSTab1.Tab = 0
    SSTab2.Tab = 0
    Set m_objToolManager = m_objTestMode.mApp.ToolManager
    Set g_objMonDrives = New clsMonDrives
    Set g_objTrendMonDrives = New clsTrendDrives
```

....

Comment: Can you add more of the code - in particular the method that you have to handle the event?

Comment: This article gives a good description of the VB6 Event system: http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/1430631/Declaring-and-Raising-Events-in-Visual-Basic-6.htm

Comment: You know, this is hard for me) but i try to explain. FirstClass has a Private Property Let IRPCAppMode_Application(RHS As Object). in this property i have a "RaiseEvent Initialize" line. So I guess if i create an instance of FirstClass in SecondClass and has a handler of Initialize in SecondClass, it fires? Am i right?

Comment: It should, depending on there not being any issues with your code. Post the bit of code that raises the event, and also the method that you that handles the event.

Comment: One thing you need to watch out here is that there is a system event on all classes in VB named Initialize, so you may be confusing that event handler with the one you are trying to catch.  The method you should be watching is fClass_Initialize.  Try to set a breakpoint in there and run (F5) and see if you get an event.

Answer (score 0):

The Initialize event is already there in your class natively, so if you try to create your own it will be ignored.  Just take your code (get rid of all the custom event code) and put it in the existing Initialize event and you will be fine.

The Initialize event gets fired whenever you create a new instance of your class.  So, if you create an instance of FirstClass with SecondClass you need your Initialize event to go in FirstClass.  That way it will get fired when you create your instance of FirstClass.  So no, SecondClass's Class_Initialize event isn't an event of FirstClass, it's an event of SecondClass.